# NoSuchObjectDefinition Found exception: Cannot find definition for object

Tags: c#, console-application, spring.net

I am new to Spring.Net. I have created simple console application and wanted to get object of class.

Code:

```
namespace ConsoleApplicationApring
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IApplicationContext context = new XmlApplicationContext(
                @"E:\VS Projects\ConsoleApplicationApring\ConsoleApplicationApring\XMLFile1.xml");

            Car car = (Car)context.GetObject("MyCar");
        }
    }

    public interface ICar
    {
        void Move();
    }

    public class Car : ICar
    {

        public void Move()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("In the Car");
        }
    }
}
```

XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="spring">
      <section name="context" type="Spring.Context.Support.ContextHandler, Spring.Core"/>
      <section name="objects" type="Spring.Context.Support.DefaultSectionHandler, Spring.Core" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <spring>
    <context>
      <resource uri="config://spring/objects"/>
    </context>

    <objects xmlns="http://www.springframework.net"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.net http://www.springframework.net/xsd/spring-objects.xsd">
      <object name="MyCar"
      type="ConsoleApplicationApring.Car, ConsoleApplicationApring" >
      </object>
    </objects>
  </spring>
</configuration>
```

When I run application, I get the exception on line "`Car car = (Car)context.GetObject("MyCar");`" NoSuchObjectDefiniation found : Can not find Definition of Object[MyCar]

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your xml file is like an application configuration file (`app.config`), but when using an an `XmlApplicationContext` like you do, it should be a plain xml file, see for instance [this example](https://github.com/serra/stackoverflow/blob/master/spring-questions/XmlConfig/objects.xml) of a plain xml configuration file.

Basically, your `XMLFile1.xml` should be something like:

```xml
<objects xmlns="http://www.springframework.net">
  <object name="MyCar"
  type="ConsoleApplicationApring.Car, ConsoleApplicationApring" >
  </object>
</objects>
```

This documented in [section 5.2.2 of the docs](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/objects.html#objects-factory-instantiation).

Comment: @Marjin: Thanks for your time. Is it necessary to have the app.config and xml file separate? Can't we have both things in single file?

Comment: Yes you can use app.config, see section [declarative configuration of the container in App.config/Web.config](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/objects.html#d4e437) of [the docs](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/)

Comment: @user2323308 any luck so far?

Comment: @Marjin: Thanks it worked. I have separated app.cofig and XML file.

Comment: That's probably the best way to go, glad it worked out for you.